# How can I make <tr> wider in <thead>?

Tags: css

[image]

CSS Part responsible for this

```
thead td.info{
        padding: 0px;
        color: #555;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

I tried to add width: (n)px

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for `colspan`, but that's just my crystal ball speaking.

Comment: td width are set per column unless you use the colspan attribute on a specific column to make it take up more column space. If you want a column in the header to take up 2 column space you would, in the html add colspan=2 and add 1 less column to the header. You can't say I want the first td in the header to be x wide and the 1st td in the body to be y width elsewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `colspan`

See: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytNz8/)**

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```